# Issues solving this physics differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By a series of easy Newton applications (irrelevant to the problem) I got to the following equation: $$\ddot{x}=-g-\frac{\mu}{m}\dot{x}^2$$ where $x$ is the position $x(t)$ and $\dot{x}$ is the derivative of the position with respect to time $t$. Of course this is a ordinary differential equation but in physics we aren't supposed to do it like that, but instead transform it always to a separable differential equation. The trick here is to do $\dot{v}=\ddot{x}$ and $\dot{x}=v$ so that we have now a separable equation $$\dot{v}=-g-kv^2$$ can't we now just separate the variables like $$\frac{dv}{-g-kv^2}=dt$$ and integrate to get the velocity and then integrate again to get the position? Because my book does a cool trick which is $\dot{v}=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=v' v$ and so we can just now find the position in terms of the velocity

Comment: This equation is only valid as long as $v$ is positive, the object moving against gravity. Moving downwards the friction term needs the other sign, to again counter-act the current movement.